# 'IntegratorKey xxxx for user Id xxx does not have access to API version v2' Docusign JWT API error

Tags: docusignapi

I get `IntegratorKey xxxx for user Id xxx does not have access to API version v2` error when calling the DocuSign rooms API. My requests work against the Esign API. I've gone through the consent process. Here's my code:

```
from docusign_esign import ApiClient
import requests

api_client = ApiClient()
oauth = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
    client_id=integration_key,
    user_id=user_id,
    oauth_host_name='account.docusign.com',
    private_key_bytes=private_key,
    expires_in=3600,
        scopes=(
            'signature',
            'impersonation',
            'dtr.company.read',
            'dtr.company.write',
            'dtr.rooms.read',
            'dtr.rooms.write',
            'dtr.documents.read',
            'dtr.documents.write'
        )
)

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {oauth.to_dict()["access_token"]}',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

rep = requests.get(
    f'https://rooms.docusign.com/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/rooms',
    headers=headers
)
```

`rep.text` returns `{"message":"IntegratorKey xxxx for user Id xxxx does not have access to API version v2. Attempted to access http://rooms.docusign.com/restapi/v2/accounts/xxx/rooms","errorCode":null}`

Comment: what is the code that generates the error exactly? what URL exactly you call?

Comment: @InbarGazit - I've updated my post with all of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the Rooms API in production without first going through the Go-Live process.
The Go-Live process for the Rooms API is a bit different at this time.

Email go-live@docusign.com with the words "Rooms go-live" in the subject line, providing the following information:

- The name and email of a Production Admin user, who can be any member
  of the account with full administrative permissions
- Your production API Account ID
- Your demo API Account ID
- The integration key of the application in the demo environment to be
  pushed into production
- The date range within which the 20+ required Rooms API calls were
  performed

More information can be found here - https://developers.docusign.com/rooms-api/guides/golive

Comment: That's it! I didn't realize the Rooms API had a separate process, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Items to check:

1. Did this work in the developer sandbox (demo.docusign.net) with (account-d.docusign.com as the IdP)?
2. Did you complete go-live process?
3. In production, you need to create a new private key for the production version of the integration key. The demo (developer sandbox) and production integration keys share the same guid value but are actually two separate keys with two sets of settings.
4. Is the user Id from a production account?
5. Did the user Id grant consent to the integration key within the production system? Either via Administrative Consent (blanket consent) or via Individual Consent.
6. First try with just the `signature` (the impersonation scope is not needed). The problem could be that your integration key needs special permissions to access the `dtr.*` scopes